# Jquery changing class one row on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm using backbone, jquery and handlebars on my project.

I'm trying to change row class just on click.
I mean if I click edit button (right of the table), it changes the class.

Look the table screenshot to understand.

[image]

AdminTableView.js

```
var addAdminPanelView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el:$(".page"),
  events:{
      'click #editButton':'editEvent',
      'click #deleteButton':'deleteEvent'
  },


  editEvent:function(){
      console.log("edit");
      this.$el.children().find("th").addClass("info");
  },
```

My template

```
 <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr class="active">
    {{#travels}}
    <th>{{user.department.departmentName}}</th>
    <th>{{user.managerID}}</th>
    <th>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</th>
    <th>Seyahat Başlangıcı</th>
    <th>Seyahat Sonu</th>
    <th>{{location}}</th>
    <th>{{travelPurpose}}</th>
    <th>{{travelCost}}</th>
    <th>{{projectCode}}</th>
    <th> <a href="/#travel">
        <span id="deleteButton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>
    </a>
        <a href="#">
            <span id="editButton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        </a>
    </th>
    {{/travels}}
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

If I click any edit button, all rows have added class "info"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the event if fired on the "edit" button click.

But you have to know on which row.
The use of `.target` as in "event.target" may help to find the parent row.

Try this:

```
editEvent:function(e){
      console.log("edit");
      $(e.target).closest("tr").addClass("info");
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `$( "editButton" ).parent( ".active" ).addClass( "yourClass" );` or this
`$( "editButton" ).parent( "tr" ).addClass( "yourClass" );`
I hope it'll work